# Excel Creating Hyperlink Data from two columns

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel I have two columns say ID and Link both are text
I have used the below macro.

```
Sub HyperAdd()

    'Converts each text hyperlink selected into a working hyperlink

    For Each xCell In Selection
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=xCell, Address:=xCell.Formula
    Next xCell

End Sub
```

But the above macro makes current seletion cells with address same as its cell value.

So How do I get link in "ID" column with hyperling address details coming from column "Link"

Comment: Great. Rajesh. I'll move the comment to answer. Please accept so others can benefit going forward.

Comment: Please tell me how to accept at clicking on tick mark is showing popup that you can accept in three minutes but nothing happens then.

Comment: Because you are kind of new, I think there may be some timing issue with when you can accept. Try again in 3 minutes. It should work. And welcome to SO, by the way. I hope you enjoy it here. I've found it VERY useful. If it doesn't work, comment back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is want you want...

Assuming the `link` column is 1 cell to the right of `ID`...

`ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=xCell, Address:=xCell.Offset(,1)`

You can adjust the offset as needed for how many columns away you are.

Answer (score 0):

Column A   -  Column B    -  Column C

ABCCompany - William Smith  - wsmith@abcco.com

=HYPERLINK(C2, B2)
William Smith will be a hyperlink with the link being wsmith@....

Check out this link.  Much easier. 
https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/03/23/excel-hyperlink-function/